# How to extract value out of column with list of dictionary using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe

```
| date | value
|------|------|
|2020-08-12| [{'action_type': 'video_view', 'value': '527'}]|
|2020-08-12|[{'action_type': 'video_view', 'value': '662'}]|
|2020-07-01| [{'action_type': 'video_view', 'value': '69'}]|
```

My desired output should be

```
| date | value
|------|------|
|2020-08-12|527|
|2020-08-12|662|
|2020-07-01|69|
```

PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 0):

Given the value column contains array data, you can extract it as follows:

```
df['value'] = df['value'].apply(lambda data: data[0].get('value'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily by using `str` accessor:

```
df['value'] = df['value'].str[0].str['value']
```

And if you need to do some mathematics and calculation by `value` column, don't forget to also change the type to numeric like below:

```
df['value'] = df['value'].astype(int)
```